# Can't access gRPC Reflection server

Tags: macos, postman, grpc

Im trying to connect via gRPC Reflection to my server using Postman and grpc_cli

in Postman i get error:

`Could not load server reflection. Details: 13 INTERNAL: Received RST_STREAM with code 2 triggered by internal client error: Protocol error`

in grpc_cli i get error:

`Received an error when querying services endpoint. ServerReflectionInfo rpc failed. Error code: 14, message: failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv6:%5B2a06:98c1:3121::3%5D:443: No route to host, debug info: UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv6:%5B2a06:98c1:3121::3%5D:443: No route to host {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-07-27T15:21:38.424037+04:00"}`

I tried from my Win computer and Postman works just fine. Any ideas why this can be?